# Google+ Sign-In button fails with Uncaught SecurityError

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus, google-cloud-endpoints

I am getting this error on my Chrome console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin https://<my-appspot-id>.appspot.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

The symptom, is that when I click the Google+ sign-in button, A Google Auth window/popup/frame appears and nothing happens.

As you can see, I am browsing my site using **https** already. My web application OAuth configuration is also set to use https (javascript origins field) .

Local testing works fine.

What is wrong with my setup?

Comment: I found this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25065194/google-sign-in-uncaught-securityerror
to provide a solution that worked for me.