# Google+ Sign-In - Uncaught SecurityError

Tags: javascript, django, authentication, google-plus, google-oauth

I'm implementing Google+ Sign-In's hybrid / one-time auth code flow and experiencing this error in Chrome's JS console after the sign-in prompts and granting the app permission, presumably when Google's code tries to call back to the button:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://ww2.fa.org" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.`

This does not seem to occur in Safari or IE and a similar permission error occurs sometimes in Firefox, but is reproducible more often than not in Chrome. Refreshing the frame with the sign-in button (after following the google-side prompts) will usually result in the refreshed button "knowing" that the sign-in was successful a call to the success handler... it should *always* work without a refresh, but just doesn't.

Any thoughts? The sign-in is at https://ww2.fa.org/gauth/ and it only requests the email scope if you're inclined to take a look!﻿

Answer (score 16):

The way I got rid of this error message is to add `https://accounts.google.com` to the `AUTHORIZED JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS` in your OAuth client settings in Cloud Developers Console under API & auth -> Credentials.

**Update**

That actually didn't fix it and the problem resurfaced again when I switched to using `gapi.auth.signIn` instead of `gapi.login.render`. The problem as described in the comments in [this post](https://plus.google.com/+JamesCridland/posts/PixJ4MC5wqt) was that serialization of the `g-oauth-window` attribute of the `authResult` when sending it to your backend. Removing that parameter or sending just the attributes you need fixed it for me.

```
var signInCallback = function(authResult) {
  delete authResult['g-oauth-window'];
  ajaxCallToBackend(authResult);
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for: `delete authResult['g-oauth-window'];`!

Comment: Just don't stringify the authResult.

it puzzeled me bigtime. This was a fix.

Comment: @YuxuanChen try debugging the authResult you're getting and see if there are any other non-serializable objects (similar to g-oauth-window) and delete them before serializing the result.

Comment: @mkhatib I found out it's one of my Chrome extensions that tried to alter the page and caused the error

Answer (score 8):

If you get the same error and the above method posted by Adam didn't work for you (it didn't work for myself) try the method below.

I overcame the problem by disabling any chrome extensions that I had installed that read and change the rendered HTML and ones that rewrite page headers and inject an sort of JavaScript in to the page.

One such extension(the one causing my `Blocked a frame with origin "https://apis.google.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://example.com` error) was namely Ripple Emulator (Beta) 0.9.15
A browser based html5 mobile application development and testing tool which "Reads and changes the all your data on the websites you visit" as it states in the extensions permission details.

Another such extension I disabled was ModHeader 1.2.4 Modify the Request Headers which also "Reads and changes the all your data on the websites you visit".

Just have a look at your Chrome extensions and eliminate any you suspect modifying pages.

Comment: Removing Ripple Emulator  solved this for me. Thanks

Comment: Same problem for me on Chrome, though I just ran my app on incognito and didn't have to figure out which annoying extension is causing this error.